# Globally change C/C++ build settings

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, build, settings

How can I add the -std=c++11 flag to ALL PROJECTS in eclipse?  I understand I can change this setting for an individual project by going to Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Settings...

I would like to change this for all new C++ projects.

The only solution I have found so far is to use one project.